# Running time of logical operator versus boolean operation

Tags: time

```
return true; 

return i == 1;
```

Do they have the same running time?

Or `return i == 1;` requires 1 more extra time?

Comment: Which language is this for?

Comment: java language..

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of return you want. For a boolean method, it is preferable to return "true". I == 1 is much less clear, especially you take an unnecessary check.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a big difference - both execute in the same time.

However, if you have a small project, then returning either `true` or `false` / `1` or `0` is totally fine and will execute equally. Even if there is a difference, `1` or `0` would execute about 0.00000000000003 milliseconds faster, which is unnoticeable.

But, if you have a large project, then returning `1` or `0` will be faster. There would still be a difference in a couple of milliseconds (about 0.2ms). If your code has a massive loop that iterates thousands of times, it would make a difference.

In C, it is preferred and recommended that you return `1` or `0` for performance and speed, but it really depends in what language you are working with. Returning `true` or `false` is just a more human-readable version of saying return `1` or `0`.